# Magento cant change product quantity in backend

Tags: php, magento, product, inventory

I have a strange problem in magento. Everything I change in the "Inventory" tab of a product, gets resettet after I click on "save".

Has someone had a similar problem in the past?

Is there a way to simulate the saving progress step by step, so I can see where the error appears?

Until now I have tried to:

- Disable all addons
- Reindex everything new
- Delete the complete cache in backend/via SQL/via ssh
- Delete all products and categorys

Sorry for the lack of information. If you need any information please feel free to ask.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: in console did you see any error?

Comment: You mean Javasrcipt console? I just checked it. No Errors.

Comment: hello at the save action of the controller there is method set data can you debug the $data variable and check which data is that , if still not work then need to check the observer event that fire after save the Product

Comment: Hi Jayram, could you please give me further information where I can find the set data method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out, where the problem was:
I have over 4000+ different product attributes. Everytime I save a product, the information of all 4000 attributes are getting transmitted over post-method. This seems to be too much, and the URL are getting cutted after a fixed value of characters. So the quantity information does not getting transmitted.

Every product has only 1-30 attributes filled with information, the rest is blank. But which attributes are filled depends on the specific product. I have choosen this method of creating an attribute for each information, because I would like to set individuality if information is searchable or filterable.

The solution was to increase max_input_vars in php.ini.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution may help you

I tracked this down into app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php.

The event catalog_product_save_after calls the saveInventoryData method which in turn calls the _prepareItemForSave method.

Around line 225:

```
$originalQty = $product->getData('stock_data/original_inventory_qty');
if (strlen($originalQty)>0) {
  $item->setQtyCorrection($item->getQty()-$originalQty);
}
```

If you comment out this line:

```
$item->setQtyCorrection($item->getQty()-$originalQty);
```

It seems to correct the problem & stock levels now stay correct when saving a product whilst simultaneously creating / canceling an order on both the front & back-end of the website.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer. I have comment out the line. But nothing has changed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: which magento version you used?

Comment: Hi dhaval, please see my updated  question.  Version 1.9.1.0